# Is there a way to append 2 arguments into a list?

Tags: python

I'm making a password generator.

```
import random
pw = []
MAX_LIMIT = 100
random_string = ''

#random str generator
for i in range(10):
    random_integer = random.randint(0, MAX_LIMIT)
    random_string += (chr(random_integer))

#password saving
pw.append(random_string,'{}'.format(random.randint(0,10)))
```

and I am trying to append `random_string` into the list `pw`, with a `.format(random.randint(0,10))` on the end of the random string. However, it is not letting me append 2 arguments.

I want my final outcome to look something like this.

```
'6;?2^0D\x1c]\x1b'9
```

with the 9 on the end being the `random.randint(0,10)`

cheers lads

Comment: You would need to store a `tuple` or `list` inside your list. You won't be able to add an `int` to the end of the string as the string is terminated after you close the quotations. Such as; `pw.append((random_string,str(random.randint(0,10))))`

Comment: `pw = [random_string,'{}'.format(random.randint(0,10))]` why do you have to append? just assign the variable a new list value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know what the problem is, but I know how to fix it.

For one, try making the randint that is formated a string by using the `str` function.

Also, you could use `+` instead of `,`:

```
pw.append(random_string + str(random.randint(0,10)))
```

As said in a comment, trying to keep the int outside is impossible.